# Why doesn't creating a new Android application project in Android studio come in with default activity and layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.0. 
When I created a new project, I was prompted with this dialog
[image]

I specified the activity name and the layout name. However after I imported the project, as told so from [Android studio no main activity, no layouts on a new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551756/android-studio-no-main-activity-no-layouts-on-a-new-project),
this is all I see
[image]

Does anyone know where i can find the main layout and java file for main activity. I don't even see a layout folder under res. The Manifest is empty as well; it doesn't contain any activities.

Comment: There was no need to import a project -- the question you cite is from a very early beta of Android Studio, about 16 months ago. That being said, I have not seen Android Studio fail to create the activity if you actually went through that portion of the new-project wizard. You might consider trying to create an activity now by choosing New > Activity > Blank Activity from the main menu or from the context menu (right-click over `java`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, why it happened with you. But you can create layout folder and add xml files. But wont forget change AndroidManifest, and create java file. Did you try create projects with other default layout?

Comment: I got some build error but o well, it's not that hard to create an activity, add it to the manifest,...